# Trans-Siberian trip in August

Tags: trains, tickets, russia, trans-siberian

I want to travel through Russia for 30 days from St. Petersburg to Vladivostok. I'm currently learning Russian and should finish A2 in August when I want to start the trip.

I read about booking the train tickets and found out, that it's possible to buy the tickets at the train stations so you can be more flexible. However I also read that the tickets in summer can be more expensive than usually. Is it still worth it to buy the tickets in Russia or should I stay safe (also in regards to having a safe tickets in case they are sold out?) and book the tickets now? Especially since I want to make 3-4 stops during the trip.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it reasonable to do the Trans-Siberian/Mongolian without pre-booking all the train tickets?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26283/is-it-reasonable-to-do-the-trans-siberian-mongolian-without-pre-booking-all-the)

Comment: I don't see anything regarding booking the tickets online vs buying them there.

Comment: It is certainly answered in there. I checked the answers and each gives an important piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

I did much train travel in the area (Murmansk, St P, Moscow, Volgograd, Astrakhan, Aktau, and Novosibirsk, Yekaterinburg, Irkutsk, Ulan Bator) back in 2011, and aside from the final leg from Irkutsh to Ulan Bator, all were trivial to book a day in advance.  I had to wait two days from Irkutsk.

I also had trouble in Almaty to Astana - trains were booked out for 5 days in advance.

Otherwise, all were done in the station of depature, on the day or the day prior.